# python dict inserts tuple instead of string

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dict object and I'm trying to add a basic string field

```
listing['Source'] = 'Bright'
```

However when I inspect the updated dict, the value got inserted as a tuple, not a dict

```
<class 'tuple'>: ('Bright',)
```

Comment: Could not replicate, works fine for me.

Comment: kill kernel and recheck.